# rewrite sql function to pure spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have code which i am trying to optimize as one way I want to try rewrite sql code into pure Spark
now i have this sql:

```
val df_result_week_agg = sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT group_id, client_id ,m_id ,min(date) stats_date ,sum(trans_cnt) trans_cnt,sum(revenue) revenue,count(DISTINCT id) cust_total, count(distinct returning_hash_id) loyal_cust_total ,'W' time_period  FROM customers  GROUP BY group_id, client_id , me_id, year(date),date_sub(to_date(date),date_format(to_date(date), 'u')-1)")
```

Is there a some article or how to which can help me to rewrite it?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance difference between writing SQL queries or writing DataFrame code, they both “compile” to the same underlying plan that we specify in DataFrame code.

Both methods use exactly the same execution engine and internal data structures. At the end of the day all boils down to the personal preferences.

For the different available functions on DataFrame, refer to: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame

In the above query, as you are just grouping and aggregating, you can use groupBy DataFrame function:

```
df.groupBy('group_id', 'client_id', 'me_id').agg({'date': 'min', 'trans_cnt': 'sum'})
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't know that there is no difference. I guess ill stick with SQL i know better than pure spark :)

Comment: by chance may be you know if i will create df.createOrReplaceTempView("name") will it . work as df.cache(). or do I need to do cash somehow differently?

Comment: df.createOrReplaceTempView("name") -- will create or replace a local temporary view with the "name" from dataframe df. It enables you to write SQL queries on DataFrame (without creating view, you will not be able to write SQL queries directly on DataFrame, however you can write DataFrame functions).

Comment: yes I understad that, but how I can cache it in instance memory ?

Comment: calling df.cache() is not mandatory to convert dataframe to sql temp view, but if you are querying dataframe multiple times (i.e referencing dataframe multiple times in functions), then caching will yield the better performance. Hope this clears, there are multiple storage levels we can cache the dataframe, suggest you to check the documentation

Comment: yes , i am calling . this temp view . multiple times in different dfs, that's why I want to cache it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to use

```
dbDf0.createOrReplaceTempView("name_for_Table_1");
dbDf0.cache();
dbDf0.count();
```

Now you can write SQL on top of name_for_Table_1